# Is it possible to Style Angular-Strap TypeAhead

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, angular-strap

I am using **AngularStrap**, (*TypeAhead*), trying to make the substring in the matched items to stand out, like either make them bold (like jquery autocomplete) or change the background of the characters ta different color
**Cal**ifornia 
Techni**cal**

I thought this should be possible by changing css (if I know they have a selector for the matched substring) Or use of template/$templatecache
no luck so far
EDIT: In this plnkr I can see the drop down menu items have user input highlighted/bolded  but cannot see why and how it happens:

```html
<input type="text" class="span3" ng-model="typeaheadValue" bs-typeahead="typeahead">
```

plnkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/Yjff9DiLnGqi2x1E5D2q?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The typeahead dropdown menu items can be styled through `.dropdown-menu a`. Matched text is regexed' to `<strong>match></strong>` i.e style those through `.dropdown-menu a strong`. Example :

```css
/* style the dropdown items */
.dropdown-menu a {
  font-family : 'courier new';
  font-size: 110%;
}

/* styling matched text */
.dropdown-menu a strong {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

forked plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/LpdRiH9DxeRiAib3MOnn?p=preview**